# How do I set up my model associations for an conference registration app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I've been playing around with writing a RoR 4.2 app that will allow the following behaviors:

1. Admin users to create a list of conference courses that will include topic, description, etc
2. Conference attendees can register with the website and then select the conference courses they'd like to attend.
3. Conference attendees should not be able to create conference courses, only to select from a list of courses listed in the database and to select them to attend. The must be a way to associate many users with the same course.
4. When a user selects a course, the seating capacity for that course should be decremented (the details of this aspect of the solution are a secondary requirement at the time)

For the sake of discussion, let's say I am using Devise with user roles all figured out and configured. So I have one user.rb model/table. 
I also created a model/table called course.rb.
I created a join model/table called course_selection.rb.

I configured these tables using the has_many through associations with the join table belonging to each like so:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :course_selections
  has_many :courses, :through => :course_selections
end

class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :course_selections
  has_many :users, :through => :course_selections
end

class CourseSelection < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :course
end
```

I have this set up and am able to create new users, but the users with non-admin roles are able to create courses (but I haven't set up any kind of role based exclusions for these users to prevent them from creating courses). When I call a RESTful route such as 
http://localhost:3000/users/3/courses
I am expecting to see only a list of courses associated with this particular user. Instead I am seeing ALL the courses listed in the database.

My questions are:

1. Can the model associations strategy I've selected be used to accomplish the behavioral goals I've specified?
2. How would the controllers be set up so that a user's course selection is established, but that they are not using the new/create methods to actually create the course?
3. How would the forms be set up (I'm using simple_form) to allow the user to select from the list of existing courses?

Thanks for your help. I haven't found any tutorials that seem to address this challenge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can the model associations strategy I've selected be used to accomplish the behavioral goals I've specified?

Yes, those models are a fine start.

> How would the controllers be set up so that a user's course selection is established, but that they are not using the new/create methods to actually create the course?

The typical Rails REST-like way is to have a controller `CourseSelectionsController` that manages the association.

Suppose you have a view page where a user can select a course. The view would submit the data to the CourseSelectionsController, with params `user_id` and `course_id`. The controller then creates the `CourseSelection` model, which associates the user and course.

The CourseSelectionsController would have typical actions for "create", "read", "delete". If the course selection also has other data, such as a price, or time slot, etc. then there can be an action for "update".

By the way, in your kind of application, the middle model is often called `Enrollment` instead of `CourseSelection`, and the REST controller is called `EnrollmentsController`.

> How would the forms be set up (I'm using simple_form) to allow the user to select from the list of existing courses?

Typically in `app/views/course_selections`. The form is based on CourseSelections (not Users, and not Courses). The form shows a list of courses. When the user submits the form, it does a PUT (or POST) to CourseSelectionsController.

If you want the form to be able to handle multiple courses, one way is to use AJAX as each course is selected or unselected. Another way is to use multiple select fields, and make a controller method that can iterate on all the selected/unselected courses.

Comment: Thank you. This makes sense! I will try this and let you know how I do.

Comment: This information provided the answer to my question. Much appreciated!